# App crashed after enable or disable calendar from settings

Tags: ios, iphone, ekeventstore

I have implemented EKEventStore, EKCalendar in my app to make the EKEvent within the app. It is working fine until or unless I didn't change permissions from the settings. But when I changed the requested access (on/off or off/on) from the settings, the app get crashed. I am unable to find the error. If someone has idea then please help me out. Here is the code I have implemented :

```
 self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
 [self checkEventStoreAccessForCalendar];

 -(void)checkEventStoreAccessForCalendar
{
EKAuthorizationStatus status = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
switch (status)
{
   case EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: [self accessGrantedForCalendar];
        break;
    case EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: [self requestCalendarAccess];
        break;
    case EKAuthorizationStatusDenied:
    case EKAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Privacy Warning" message:@"Permission was not granted for Calendar"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
        break;
        default:
        break;
} }

  -(void)requestCalendarAccess
 {
   [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted,  
NSError *error)
 {
     if (granted)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });
     }
 }];
}

 -(void)accessGrantedForCalendar
{
self.defaultCalendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
EKEvent *addEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
addEvent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textcontainer.text];
}
```

#pragma mark EKEventEditViewDelegate

```
-(void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
      didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
 {
     if (action != EKEventEditViewActionCanceled)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          });
     }
 }];
 }

- (EKCalendar *)eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendarForNewEvents:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
{
return self.defaultCalendar;
 }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and say on which line you have the crash

Comment: @LombaX I have set the breakpoints to all the methods.. but it didn't go to any method before crash.

Comment: I might be wrong on this but does your app not restart once settings have been changed? I have noticed this with a couple of apps. Your app might not actually be crashing but rather a "force shutdown", again I might be wrong on this.

Comment: @sbarow it opened . but didn't work..

Comment: @MinkleGarg assuming that you have set the breakpoint correctly, it means that the crash is happening before that two methods. What happens if you set a breakpoint on the first line of `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` ?

Comment: it doesn't go to didfinishlaunching method... app crashed at main method int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }}

Answer (score 0):

When your app goes to the background it should save all its states and should be prepared to get killed. When someone switches off access to calendar, the easiest way for the system to deals with that is to kill your app, and that is why its happening. If you switch back to your app by clicking 'Back to Your-App' on top, you can notice that your app will be launching from the beginning, not from where you left. Try not using the breakpoint and you will notice the change.

- So its not a crash actually.